# Why can't I login to mysql with --login-path=local?

Tags: mysql

I just updated a MySQL database from 5.5 to 5.6. I'm attempting to [follow best practices](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html) so I used `mysql_config_editor` to create a `.mylogin.cnf` file:

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=example --password
```

However, when I try `mysql --login-path=local` I get this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'example'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

However, I can still login using `mysql -u example -p`, and then pasting the password at the prompt. I've triple-checked that I'm using the correct password in my `mysql_config_editor` command.

My grants look like this:

```
mysql> show grants;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for example@localhost                                                 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'example'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret>  |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `example`.* TO 'example'@'localhost'                 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is the output to `/var/log/mysql/error.log` when I restart MySQL:

```
160223 12:31:41 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
160223 12:31:42 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2016-02-23 12:31:43 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-02-23 12:31:43 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.29) starting as process 31337 ...
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)

2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)

2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam_recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.29 started; log sequence number 1660606
SSL error: Unable to get certificate from '/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem'
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Warning] Failed to setup SSL
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Warning] SSL error: Unable to get certificate
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2016-02-23 12:31:43 31337 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.29'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Do you see anything in the log that might indicate why I can't login using the `--login-path` option?

Comment: Tried changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` or with `--password=""`?

Comment: @Justinas I tried 127.0.0.1 and got the same error. As for the password: `mysql_config_editor: option '--password' cannot take an argument`

Comment: than how you pass password to `mysql_config_editor` if it cannot take argument?

Comment: It prompts for a password after you enter the command, just like `mysql -p`

Answer (score 2):

Add double quotes to your password. It worked for me.

Comment: double quotes and also single quotes worked for me.  My guess is that the password has special characters that are otherwise messing something up.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the socket to log in locally. Try specifying the `mysql_config_editor` command with the `--socket=/path/to/mysqld.sock` option that's correct for your MySQL instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and thought I'd share my solution in my case:

#### TLDR: Manually Connecting Works because the Default Host is Not Local, But You're Configuring MySQL_Config_Editor with Local

Your example of logging in omits the `-h` parameter: `mysql -u example -p`.  To see what host `mysql` is connecting to, look at the results of: `mysql --print-defaults`.  You get something like...

```
--user=ExampleUser
--password=*****
--host=host.example.com
--port=12345
```

The `--host` value you see here should *exactly* match what you are putting into the `host` value here, in order to make it work correctly:

```
mysql_config_editor set --host=host.example.com --user=example --password
```

In addition, I recommend trying *without* the `--login-path=local`, since it may actually well be that your host, according to the defaults, *is not* `local` or `localhost`.

According to the docs, the `login-path` parameter contains "options that specify which MySQL server to connect to and which account to authenticate as." (Source: [**Dev.MySQL.com**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_login-path).)  So, I think your problem may be like mine: a mismatch of the right `host` value while also dropping `--login-path=local`.